# System Microphone not showing as option in Firefox (or Chrome?) for Google hangouts. How do I get it to appear?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, microphone, google-hangouts

I'm trying to use Google Hangouts a fair bit for video calls these days (aren't we all?). In Firefox, for other websites, my system microphone **(RealTek(R) Audio)** is showing up just fine in the permissions dropdown that asks to use my Mic. But for Google hangouts in particular, it doesn't show that, and only shows my other "microphone" **(2 - USB PnP Audio Device)** which is for an external headphone mount on my desk and doesn't currently have a microphone wired into it. Chrome has the same problem with Hangouts, but I haven't tried it yet with other sites.

This puts me in the awkward situation of using my phone to make calls for the sound. All the googling shows is how to allow the microphone - which doesn't help when your microphone won't show up at all. Does someone have a fix for this?